# Showing a mask of MovieClip with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mask, movieclip

Is it possible to display a mask object using AS3?

I have a MovieClip called `myMC`, then I mask `myMC` with the MovieClip called `myMask`. MOVIE_CLIP and MASK are library MovieClips.

```
var myMC:MovieClip = new MOVIE_CLIP();
var myMask:MovieClip = new MASK();
myMC.mask = myMask;
```

Of course, `myMC` won't show.

What I want is that `myMC` is only displayed in `myMask`, and not outside it, with `myMask` reamining visible.

Comment: is there any reason to not put the object in front of the other? that should do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be quite honest with you, this isn't possible AFAIK. A mask, by definition, is invisible. What you would need is to have the mask be the SHAPE you want, and then have an additional MovieClip that shows whatever visual elements you would have shown on the mask.

Case and point, if you wanted to use a glass-pane graphic as your mask, you would need to have a glass-pane graphic, the mask with the same dimensions, and then the MovieClip you're masking underneath that mask.

I hope that helps.